# CMS build fully with OOP?

Tags: php, oop, content-management-system

I guess you've heard of popular CMS systems like Drupal and Wordpress. Although they are great and helpful for a lot of projects, I'm wondering if they are any similar CMS systems built entirely with the new and improved OOP features. I will like to check them out. If you know any, please let me know, but please don't mention PHP frameworks...

Comment: I don't understand the part about not mentioning PHP frameworks. There are high-class, 100% OOP frameworks out there, what's wrong with them?

Comment: @Pekka: I think he means he wants a fully built CMS, rather than just a framework.

Comment: I only use CMSes written in functional languages, because they don't have side effects.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! The benefit of a CMS is that it helps you build a default and fully functional website in a matter of minutes after which you start customizing by adding custom plugins/modules if there is the case for additional functionality. That's why I want to know if there is OOP CMS as an alternative to Drupal/Wordpress.

Comment: Have you checked XOOPS? Would be better to hear what kind of website you are going to have at the end? Community, corprate, blog or ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178560/which-php-cms-has-the-best-architecture

Answer (score 0):

I was using Modx Cms (http://modx.com , code is at github https://github.com/modxcms/revolution). It is entirely object-oriented, gives a lot of flexibility for the HTML and Javascript code, has a built-in templating engine; admin panel is written in ExtJS and is also customizable.

Comment: ExtJS is customizable? You mean: Without spending month in customizing it?! O_o